# Spring Data JPA with Hibernate - OnetoMany Relationship Mapped Entities - Partial Commit Issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have a one to many relationship between two entity classes. When an error occurs during the insert of an child then partial insertion of parent happens but child record remains un-persisted. Here confgiured EntityManager is supposed to handle rollbacks for the transactions but it is not the case.

Here is the class of my entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable { 

   @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_parent", sequenceName = "seq_parent")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_parent")
    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Child> childDetails;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;

}

Now my Service Class Method :

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

 @PersistanceContext
 private EntityManager entityManger;

 @Transactional
 public void persist() {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Set<Child> childSet = new HashSet<>();
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);
    childSet.add(child );
    parent.add(childSet);
    entityManager.persist(parent);        
 }
}

Here are my JavaConfig in Spring for transactionManager and DataSource :



@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/spring/audit/auditing-dbsink-config.xml",
        "classpath:META-INF/spring/services-context.xml" })
@EnableTransactionManagement(order = 20)
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

}

app-datasource.xml :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/datasource" lookup-on-startup="true"
                     proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          parent="abstractEntityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oracle_pu"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now the problem is the TransactionManager doesn't rollback the complete transaction in case of exception occurred while persisting the child record.

Please throw some light on this as I am really not able to proceed further.

Comment: Are you handling the thrown exception anywhere?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic yes I am handling the exception to convert it into business exception and log into exception monitoring area. Does that affect the transaction handling ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic In any case, either the transaction should either save both child and parent or neither of them. But as per Nik, he is able to save only the parent (partially).Nik, can you post complete code for Parent & Child entities?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu complete code chunk is same as posted in my question. I am just creating parent and child entities intializing their required properties and then calling entity manager persist method. Any idea why the partial commit is taking place. Some clue around it ?

Comment: @Nik I don't see any `Id` declared in the `Child` class, Are you not getting any hibernate exceptions as each Entity is supposed to have `Id` attribute. That is where I was asking for the complete code for both entities. Also I don't see add method named `add` in the `Parent` class.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring does not rollback transaction when a checked exception is thrown. From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back):

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code *only* marks a transaction for rollback in the
>   case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown
>   exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors
>   will also - by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions
>   that are thrown from a transactional method do *not* result in
>   rollback in the default configuration.

More details about how to change this behaviour can be found in the linked documentation. For example, the approach I find most intuitive is to rollback transactions for all of the exceptions:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: @Dragon - I tried by putting <tx:advice but the partial commit is still happening and it not rolling back the complete transaction.

Comment: @Nik Are you throwing checked exception from the transactional context out of it?

Comment: @Dragon I am handling the exception in the service for which this persist call is initiated. The service which initiated persist call is non transactional.